# Replicate plotly plot as connected scatter plot

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

I want to plot a graph for one API, which has different versions in it throughout the years, with commits on the y axis.

I want to connect all the scatter plot dots together, with the version name on top of it.

This is my code as of now:

```
import plotly.express as px
fig = px.scatter(final_api.query("info_title=='Avi TestSeDatastoreLevel2 Object API'"), x="Year-Month", y="commits", color="info_version",title='Different Path Version found within one OAS file', width=1000, height=700)
fig.show()
fig.update_layout(yaxis_range=[0,80])
```

I am a bit stuck and new to plotly functions, so any guidance will be great. If there is any other library in which I could generate a similar plot, that would be helpful as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To realize your question, use the graph object to create a graph with markers, line segments, and annotations. The function required for a line graph is to create a staircase-like graph, so you set the shape of the line. Next, a color scale is applied to the markers of the scatter plot in order to color-code the markers. You can change this to whatever you need. Finally, use the annotation function to rotate the text. I have changed some of the data you have presented to make the graph look better.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import io

data = '''
      info_version  commits Year-Month  info_title
0       20.1.1       32    2020-08   "Avi TestSeDatastoreLevel2 Object API" 
1       18.2.8       31    2020-01   "Avi TestSeDatastoreLevel2 Object API" 
2       18.2.7       30    2019-12   "Avi TestSeDatastoreLevel2 Object API" 
3       20.1.1       29    2019-11   "Avi TestSeDatastoreLevel2 Object API" 
4       18.2.6       28    2019-10   "Avi TestSeDatastoreLevel2 Object API" 
'''

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), delim_whitespace=True)
df['Year-Month'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Year-Month']) 

import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure()

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(mode='lines',
                         x=df['Year-Month'],
                         y=df['commits'],
                         line_color='gray',
                         line_width=1,
                         line_shape='vh',
                         showlegend=False
                       )
             )

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(mode='markers',
                         x=df['Year-Month'],
                         y=df['commits'],
                         marker=dict(color=df['commits'], colorscale='Blues'),
                         showlegend=False
                        )
             )

for _,row in df.iterrows():
    fig.add_annotation(
        go.layout.Annotation(
            x=row['Year-Month'],
            y=row['commits'],
            text=row['info_version'],
            showarrow=False,
            align='center',
            yanchor='bottom',
            yshift=5,
            textangle=-90)
    )
fig.update_layout(title_text='Different Path Version found within one OAS file',
                 template='plotly_white')

fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: To extract with multiple parameters in a data frame, use the following code, which requires the same length for the zip function, but specifies it as an extraction condition based on a value. `for info1,trac in zip(df['info_title1'].unique(), df['traccar'].unique()):
    dff = df[(df['info_title1'] == info1) & (df['traccar'] == trac)]`

Comment: Try this `for traccar,year in zip(final_api['info_title'].unique(), final_api['Year'].unique()):          dff = final_api[(final_api['info_title'] == traccar) & (final_api['Year'] == year)]`

Comment: Isn't the column in final_api['Year'] a numeric column?

Comment: For example, `year=2020;final_api[final_api['Year'] == year]` will be extracted?